# Can Cmake be used to build a docker container and then build C++ code within that container?

Tags: c++, docker, makefile, cmake

I have a dockerfile I use to download images for my C++ code. I currently use a Makefile system but can use CMake in theory.

```
root
|-dockerFile
|-Makefile
|-dockerMakefile
|-CMakeLists.txt
||-target1
|||-CMakeLists.txt
|||-Makefile
|||-src
|||-inc
||-target2
|||-CMakeLists.txt
|||-Makefile
|||-src
|||-inc
```

The `dockerMakefile` is just shell script that builds and tags a docker build, then runs that container and then runs make inside that container. I suppose I can modify my script to do that with CMake but is there a more elegant way to do this directly with CMake?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom target that would run the docker commands. The only problem is that cmake by its nature is a generator, i.e. it will generate a makefile first and then you'll have to run `make` anyways. So, to me, it seems a bit pointless.